Printer color setup powershell script
I am trying to deploy PowerShell script that force printing for print window to be BnW, but user can change that, any help would be appreciated.
Additional info:
Printer is Kyocera Taskaifa 2554ci, using LPR, mapped to users via another PS script that cleanup previous printer / download and install driver / verify if printer present / cleanup after itself.
I've already dig into driver option during install and tried to analyze where this default printing color is, but no luck.
https://dam.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com/content/dam/gdam_dc/dc_global/executables/web/Kx84_UPD_8.4.1716_en_RC5_WHQL.zip
Driver install done via:
# Install driver
$infFile = "$extractPath\Kx84_UPD_8.4.1716_en_RC5_WHQL\64bit\OEMSETUP.inf"
pnputil.exe -i -a $infFile
Add-PrinterDriver -Name $targetDriverName

Printer add done via:
Add-Printer -Name $targetPrinterName -PortName $targetPortName -DriverName $targetDriverName

I have already tested chatgpt / claude, no luck too.
